# turn off logging from phantomjs

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, openshift

I am trying to use PhantomJS on an Openshift Server (Linux) using Python and Selenium.

The Error that I get using no exceptions is:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'ghostdriver.log'
```

This is the code:

```
try:
    browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()
except AttributeError:
    error = "Attribute Error"
except PermissionError:
    error= "Permission Error"
```

The solution to this is probalby turning of logging

I tried this by changing this line:

```
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()
```

To:

```
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(service_log_path=os.path.devnull)
```

But now I get the AttributeError

What is a possible solution for this problem?

Comment: Have you tried `webdriver.PhantomJS(service_log_path="/dev/null")`?

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply! Sadly it didnt work I am still getting the permission error....